# Proving a corollary of a corollary of the Mean Value Theorem (corollary-ception)

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

This is will a wordy question but here it goes:

My analysis book states the mean-value theorem and then a corollary which we will label as (1):

- Let $f$ be a differentiable function on $(a,b)$ such that $f'(x) = 0$
  for all $x \in (a,b)$. Then $f$ is a constant function on $(a,b)$.

My book then goes on to state an additional corollary which we will label as (2):

- Let $f$ and $g$ be differentiable functions on $(a,b)$ such that
  $f'=g'$ on $(a,b)$. Then there exists a constant $c$ such that $f(x)
     = g(x) + c$ for all $x \in (a,b)$.

This corollary also makes sense. I interpreted it as two functions $f$ and $g$ with parallel tangent lines at every point so that one function is an exact copy of the other except it is at a different height.

However, in the proof of (2), the book simply states "Apply [1] to the function $f-g$.

I don't see how (1) completely proves (2) because (1) only deals with functions with $f'(x) = 0$ and (2) deals with functions with f' = g' on a whole interval.

Can anyone explain this? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try applying theorem 1 to the function $f-g$.

Comment: Well that's what the book said exactly, I still don't get how using a corollary that is defined for only one case ($f'(x) = 0$) can be used to prove all cases ($f'=g'$).

Comment: Shoot, nevermind. I got it. LOL sometimes I just have to stare at something really obvious for a long time for it to be obvious.